# How to calculate 2d X-ray image projection given camera orientation (theta, phi, distance) and 3d object coordinates

Tags: python, graphics, 3d, computer-vision

I'm trying to recreate an X-ray projection

I have 3D coordinates of an object of shape (100,3), spherical coordinates of the camera (theta, phi, distance), distance from camera to image, and size of image (512x512)

There are plenty of tutorials out there but I am struggling to get plausible results

Here is what I have done so far

1. Convert spherical to cartesian

```
def spherical_2_cartesian (phi, theta, p):

    x = p * np.sin(phi) * np.cos(theta)
    y = p * np.sin(phi) * np.sin(theta)
    z = p * np.cos(phi)
    
    return x,y,z

xa,ya,za = spherical_2_cartesian (23.1, 32.6, 730.0779523)
```

2. Calculate extrinsic matrix via the ['look at'](https://ksimek.github.io/2012/08/22/extrinsic/) method

```
L = [xa,ya,za]
L = L / np.linalg.norm(L)
s = np.cross(L, [0,1,0])
s = s / np.linalg.norm(s)
u_prime = s * L
R = np.array([s, u_prime, -L])
t = np.dot(-R,[xa,ya,za])
extrinsic = np.column_stack((R, t))
```

3. Define intrinsic matrix

```
f = 1066 ## distance from source to image plane
cx, cy = 512.0/2, 512.0/2 ## image size / 2
intrisic = np.array([[f, 0, cx], [0, f, cy], [0, 0, 1]])
```

4. Convert 3d shape coords to homogenous, so shape is (100, 4)

```
mesh_homo = np.concatenate((mesh_coords,np.ones((len(mesh_coords),1))), axis=1)
```

5. Calculate 3d shape coords in camera coordinate system.

```
mesh_in_camera_coords = np.dot(extrinsic,np.swapaxes(mesh_homo, 0, 1))
```

6. Finally calculate projection and convert to x,y image coords

```
homogenous = np.dot(intrisic, mesh_in_camera_coords)
x = homogenous[0] / homogenous[2]
y = homogenous[1] / homogenous[2]
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: start with an orthogonal projection. it's easier. not all that division. -- you aren't making flat projections of a surface, you are handling a **volume**. -- you talk of a mesh. are we to assume the mesh represents a solid body of uniform density? for uniform density, you can make a simplification (otherwise there'd be products or logarithms). total attenuation along a ray is proportional to the *logarithm* of the travel distance through the medium.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thanks for your response. The mesh for this purpose can simply be through of as a point cloud, so no connective information. I want to project the 3d point cloud to a 2d image space, given the camera intrinsic and extrinsic parameters. Honestly, i'm not sure I follow regarding orthogonal projection or mesh density. Could you describe how these are relevant to the problem? Many thanks

Comment: you talk of xray. is this a medical application? how literal do you understand "xray" to be here? a point cloud has no volume. what are you trying to achieve? what is this data? what can you show? or are you simply trying to understand how computer graphics (projection matrices) work in general?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz x-ray beam from source passes through tissue and is received at detector. 3d point cloud reconstructions of organs/vessels can be created from multi-view x-rays. I have the 3d point cloud, the x-rays images and the camera parameters. Now my task is to project the 3d to the 2d image plane. I hope that makes sense. Sadly I cant share data as it confidential.

Comment: computed tomography usually results in voxel data, not point clouds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: For those interested, the correct way to build an extrinsic matrix for angiographic x-ray is described in this paper:

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6820797

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).